# youtube-dl: Use different output format if downloading a playlist

Tags: command-line, youtube-dl

I am using youtube-dl to mostly download channels or playlists. However, if it is a playlist I do not want to use the same output template as if it were a channel. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
# If it is a channel, use this:
-o ./Downloads/Channels/%(uploader)s_%(channel_id)s/%(upload_date)s_%(title)s_%(display_id)s.%(ext)s
# If it is a playlist, use this:
-o ./Downloads/Playlists/%(playlist_title)s_%(playlist_id)s/[%(playlist_index)s] %(upload_date)s_%(title)s_%(display_id)s.%(ext)s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youtube’s channel URLs have `/channel/` in them, I would just test for this string and set the option accordingly with a little function:

```bsh
yt() {
  for i in "$@"; do
    if [[ "$i" =~ .*/channel/.* ]]; then
      opt="channel"
    else
      opt="playlist"
    fi
  echo youtube-dl -o "$opt" "$i"
  done
}
```

This defines a function `yt` which loops over its arguments, sets the `opt` variable to either `"channel"` if the argument contains the string “/channel/” or `"playlist"` if not and runs `echo youtube-dl` with the option and the argument. Run it with a list of channels and playlists to see it performing:

```bsh
$ yt channel test something_with_/channel/_here
youtube-dl -o playlist channel
youtube-dl -o playlist test
youtube-dl -o channel something_with_/channel/_here
```

Replace `"channel"` with the option string (without the leading `-o`!) for channels and `"playlist"` with the one for playlists, test with real URLs whether the function now prints the correct commands and finally remove the `echo` command to make it actually run `youtube-dl`.

I keep `bash` functions in a separate file `~/.bash_functions` and source it in my `~/.bashrc`, others prefer to have functions directly in the latter file, either way you have it defined in every new terminal.